# Toggle class doesn't work with push menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

Can you help me and tell me why this code doesn't work? On click '.push-button' it should open the '#push-menu' and that works but the other part of the doesn't work instead of showing the elements on the first click and then hiding the elements on the second click, it doesn't even show them when I open the menu it is empty, just white!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".push-button").click(function () {
  $("#push-menu").toggle(
    function (){
      $('.link-item-1').addClass('active-1');
      $('.link-item-2').addClass('active-2');
      $('.link-item-3').addClass('active-3');
      $('.link-item-4').addClass('active-4');
      $('.link-item-5').addClass('active-5');
  }, function (){
      $('.link-item-1').removeClass('active-1');
      $('.link-item-2').removeClass('active-2');
      $('.link-item-3').removeClass('active-3');
      $('.link-item-4').removeClass('active-4');
      $('.link-item-5').removeClass('active-5');
   }
 );
});
});
```

Comment: looks like you have multiple `#push-menu`s in your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because the `toggle()` method no longer works in the manner you expect. It was changed several versions ago.

However, you can fix both the issue and massively simplify your code by using `toggleClass()` instead:

```
$(".push-button").click(function () {
  $('.link-item-1').toggleClass('active-1');
  $('.link-item-2').toggleClass('active-2');
  $('.link-item-3').toggleClass('active-3');
  $('.link-item-4').toggleClass('active-4');
  $('.link-item-5').toggleClass('active-5');
});
```

I would also suggest you revisit the logic you're using with regard to the classes. They are supposed to group common elements, yet you have given each element its own unique class which is the complete opposite pattern.

To make that work you could then use the same class on all elements, eg. `link-item`, then identify them by index in either JS or CSS, whenever required.

```
$(".push-button").click(function () {
  $('.link-item').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: nice answer. tight!

Comment: I will try that rn. They are with different name because they have to show differently like one should has transition-delay: 0.5s, other 0.6s, etc that is why they have different names.

Comment: I'm sure there's better methods of doing that too - but I'd suggest asking a new question for it.

Comment: Now they work but still there is a little problem, I don't have the reverse animation. When I click on the push menu they show up from left to right but when I click on the X to close the menu they just fade out, I need the reverse animation.

Comment: That's all down to how your CSS has been set up

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here I have made a fiddle, could you please fix it, because I really don't know how to make the reverse animation! Thank you very much!! http://jsfiddle.net/euds0n6x/1/

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you're trying to do with that code as you have multiple click event handlers all attached to the same element...? Also note that you only need one document.ready event handler. I tidied it up a little for you: http://jsfiddle.net/euds0n6x/4/. If you're having problems with the logic I'd suggest you open a new question including all the code as well as a clear description of what *is* happening and what you *expect* to happen.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay so I want a reverse animation. When I click on the menu button you see how the divs move from left to right. So, when I click again on the button (to close the push menu) rn they just disappear without any effect, I want them to disappear to the left from where they have come!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you help me?